# How to give background color to my checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I want to give bakground color to my checkbox. Here is my code

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
    <input type="checkbox" class="customCheckBox" name="checkbox">
    <span>data:
        <span class="font-weight-bold">user</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

But, checkbox doesn't get background color. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: i don't want the label. Just a checkbox here.

Answer (score 0):

Browser natively give some styles to many input types. If you want to override those, you'll have to redo a lot of it by yourself, but it's doable (and often done). You just have to prevent the default appearance with:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

And now you can see the checkbox can have a red background. But the checkmark doesn't appear anymore.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
    <input type="checkbox" class="customCheckBox" name="checkbox">
    <span>data:
        <span class="font-weight-bold">user</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

To add a checkmark, The simplest way I can think of is to add a pseudo-element when the input is checked:

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked::after {
    content: '✓';
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
    <input type="checkbox" class="customCheckBox" name="checkbox">
    <span>data:
        <span class="font-weight-bold">user</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your checkbox style, and use `:checked` to differentiate between checked and unchecked.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
    <input type="checkbox" class="customCheckBox" name="checkbox">
    <span>data:
        <span class="font-weight-bold">user</span>
    </span>
</div>
```